# j2me notifyDestroyed() not called in time

Tags: java-me

I have been developing a j2me application for TC65 that needs to receive the GPS data and save that data in file and this file will be sent to a server using a timer. At some instances the application closes and the console shows "notifyDestroyed() not called in time" . I called this method when I need to close the application. But the console didn't show any logs that I have put before this call. I think the system called that method before closing the application. If so what was the reason to exit the application??

Answer (score 1):

MIDP application manager(AMS) can signal midlet to move to destroyed state at anytime. It usually happens when the system is running low on resources (for example memory). Check if the destroyApp() method of your midlet is called, if it is then it is the AMS that is closing the midlet.